# Garbage in Thunderbird multipart boundaries

Tags: thunderbird

In messages I send with Thunderbird I have the following email header

> Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
> boundary="*000_160551222008756181axiscom*"

All the history is divided by lines looking like

> --*000_160551222008756181axiscom*

Those initial `--` mess things up for other mail viewers like Outlook's webmail client. Where does those `--` come from, and how do I get rid of them?

I'm using version 78.4.2 (64-bit) of Thunderbird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hyphens come from [RFC2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046). You don't normally get rid of them. Look for the problem elsewhere.

> The Content-Type field for multipart entities requires one parameter,
> "boundary". The boundary delimiter line is then defined as a line
> consisting entirely of two hyphen characters ("-", decimal value 45)
> followed by the boundary parameter value from the Content-Type header
> field, optional linear whitespace, and a terminating CRLF.